# PowerPivot not sending Authorization header in Basic Authentication to OData Svc

Tags: excel, wcf, odata, powerpivot

QA - I know the answer.

I have created a WCF Data Services OData endpoint and its all works, PowerPivot connects and I built some pivot tables.

Then I implemented a Basic Authentication HTTP handler which challenges requests not presented an Authorization header with a 401 WWW-Authenticate see link:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/basic-authentication

This works for IE; the browser pops a credentials input dialogue and IE continues to attach the header with subsequent requests, caches it.

In Excel, I can see that it sends the Authorization header in response to the initial challenge, but it doesn't cache the credentials and send the header on the next request.

**Everything is set as per the PowerPivot instructions.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to append a trailing backslash to the OData endpoint URLs when setting-up the data source/feed in PowerPivot, e.g.

```
http://localhost:50885/Service.svc/
```

A bug, but at least with a workaround, and once posted here on SO, a more easily discoverable workaround!